# How do I install python package from private github repo using jenkins?

Tags: python, git, jenkins, pip

I am able to `checkout scm` using the jenkins private key (for which the public key is in the github repo) with the github plugin. I can install on my local system (osx). But I am not able to install a python package from a private github repo from Jenkins.

Any ideas for this? I'm guessing that I need to get the token into an environment variable such as `github_repo_token=os.environ.get('GITHUB_TOKEN', 'NA')`, use that to insert it into the github url such as `"git+https://{}@github.com/owner/repo.git@master".format(github_repo_token)`, then it will work.

How can I get the token into an environment variable or pass into the setup.py script?

Answer (score 0):

1. Direct answer – make pre-install step in jenkins with `export GITHUB_TOKEN=...`, and you'll have it in `os.environ`
2. That being said, I highly recommend you going other way around. Having such `setup.py` makes your installs way less portable and hard to use in dev environments. I suggest you creating `.netrc` file in jenkins and putting token there. This way your jenkins will authorize on GH automatically (assuming you're pulling via https), and dev environments can get authorization interactively.

   Format for `.netrc` should be something like

   ```
   machine github.com login your_token
   ```

Comment: It's the ... that is beyond my understanding. I have the key in SSH Username with private key, which is used to run CI on that repo using the github plugin, but I'm not sure how to get that into the export statement. Thanks.